# How to automatically add the service providers in the providers array inside config/app.php?

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am working on a project of creating a package that can automatically add its service provider into the providers array inside `config/app.php` but I have been stuck.

The plan is after running `composer require vendor/package` the providers array will automatically append and the `psr-4` section in the main `composer.json` will be updated.

I am new to Laravel.

Comment: what have u tried?

Answer (score 0):

**COMING SOON!**

There is automatic discovery via composer in Laravel 5.5

https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-5/episodes/5

```
{
"name": "test/test",
"description": "test for laravel5.5",
"license": "MIT",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "simple",
        "email": "simple@gmail.com"
    }
],
"require": {},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Simple\\test\\": "src/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "providers": [
            "Simple\\test\\TestServiceProvider"
        ]
    }
}
}
```